# Correlation plot error division by zero matplot pandas numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a data frame with a set of (6631,26) and when I try to make a correlation plot I get the following error:

[image]

Is this because  my data set is too big? or what can I do to fix  this? I checked my counts and I know I have a few NaN values, can I skip those? I'm new at this so I'm sorry if this is not a good question.

Comment: The answer is because you have NaNs. You have to handle those first. You can of course remove them and see if the behavior changes. Removing data isn't a decision to make lightly obviously.

Comment: I know exactly which column has the NaN values. How would I make a correlation plot excluding a certain column?

Comment: Added as an answer @learnerB

Comment: `df.corr()` gives me correlation output with `NaN` as well. Example: `df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x':[1,2,3,4,4,5,67,78,8,8,99,90,0,0],
    'y':[np.nan,np.inf,31,24,41,5,23,74,8,68,89,90,0,0],
    'z':[0]*14
    
})` and `df.corr()`. Could you post few sample rows that you think are causing the error?

Comment: I believe the error is because most of my data is being read as an object. I tried to use dummies, but that does not still seem to work

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = [[1, 2, np.nan], [1, 3, np.nan], [1, 5, np.nan], [1,8, np.nan]]

data = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3'])

data.drop('Col3', axis=1).corr()
```

Where the Col3 is the column with the nans. or

```
data.drop(['Col1', 'Col3'], axis=1).corr()
```

for muliple columns with nans.

Comment: Hi, I have been trying and I still get the same error. Most of my variables are of type String. I tried using dummies and then make a correlation plot but that did not work. Is there any other way to do this? I have been stuck with this for days